# build cppcheck 1.69 on Ubuntu 11.04 fails

Tags: cppcheck

I'm trying to build cppcheck 1.69 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Command:

```
make
```

or

```
make SRCDIR=build CFGDIR=cfg HAVE_RULES=yes
```

Result:

> build/checkautovariables.cpp:527:16: error: no match for ‘operator==’
>   in ‘var == cppcheck_nullptr_impl’

Comment: If you had a nice fix since please reply your own question.

Answer (score 0):

it fails on g++ 4.1.1-4.5 due to bug #33990.
[bug in lookup of member template conversion operator for pointer to member functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33990)

and

[More C++ Idioms/nullptr](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/nullptr#Solution_and_Sample_Code)

I did an gcc 4.5 ugly fix in cxx1emu.h
replacing

```
#define nullptr cppcheck_nullptr_impl
```

with

```
#if (__GNUC__ <= 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ == 5)
#define nullptr (0)
#else
#define nullptr cppcheck_nullptr_impl
#endif
```